# Association setup for messages with recipients

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am wonder what the best way to set up the models and associations are with what I am trying to achieve.

A user can create a message. The message can have one or many recipients who are users.

How do I set it up the associations so I can view the messages that are made by a user, but also messages where the recipient is their user id? Do I do a join model, or do I do:

A user has_many messages, a message has many recipients (stores message_id and user_id) and if that's the best way how do I access the messages where the user is not the owner of the message but a recipient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User << ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message"
  has_many :recipients
  has_many :received_messages, :through => :recipients, :source => :message
end

class Message << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
  has_many :recipients
  has_many :receivers, through: :recipients
end

class Recipients<< ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User"
end
```

Then you can:

```
user = User.find(1)     # First user
user.sent_messages      # Messages sent by user
user.received_messages  # Messages received by user
```